# The compiler is unable to type-check this expression swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift

After updating xCode i am getting this error into my code :

> The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable
>   time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

The code :

```
//check popup in window frame

let spaceFromLeftSide = cutOutViewX.constant + cutOutViewWidth.constant/2 - (options.textWidth + padding*2)/2

if spaceFromLeftSide < 0{

    if options.side == .bottom {
        messageRightSpaceFromBottomDot.constant -= spaceFromLeftSide - padding
    }
    else if options.side == .top{
        messageRightSpaceFromTopDot.constant += spaceFromLeftSide - padding
    }
}

let spaceFromRightSide = cutOutViewX.constant + cutOutViewWidth.constant/2 + (options.textWidth + padding*2)/2

if spaceFromRightSide > targetView.frame.size.width{

    if options.side == .bottom {
        messageRightSpaceFromBottomDot.constant -= spaceFromRightSide - ( targetView.frame.size.width )
    }
    else if options.side == .top{
        messageRightSpaceFromTopDot.constant += spaceFromRightSide - ( targetView.frame.size.width )
    }
}
```

Error in line :

```
let spaceFromRightSide = cutOutViewX.constant + cutOutViewWidth.constant/2 + (options.textWidth + padding*2)/2
```

how to fix this ?

Comment: Are any of the values in that code calculated values? e.g. `options.textWidth`? You might try specifying the class for each variable, rather than relying on type inference. e.g. `let spaceFromLeftSide: CGFloat = `

Comment: When this happens, a process named SourceKitService uses more than 13GB memory on my 8GB machine. Usually it uses a little more than 300MB. It appears, some expressions create memory leaks in the build process.

Comment: I have to admit I rolled my eyes when I saw this error

Comment: Here is another ridiculous example: return

Comment: Free up memory and the error goes away! :)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

> The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

This error appears when swift compiler finds the expression calculation lengthy. For more details [check here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-fix-the-error-expression-was-too-complex-to-be-solved-in-reasonable-time)

To resolve this, you just need to break your expression into smaller parts. Just like:

```
let cutOutxOrigin = 3 * cutOutViewX.constant / 2
let actualPadding = (options.textWidth + padding * 2) / 2

let spaceFromRightSide = cutOutxOrigin + actualPadding
```

Comment: I've seen this before and didn't understand why, and ended up making code simpler. This answer made things clear. Thanks.

Comment: @Pelanes I'm not here to defend XCode, but this isn't caused by the IDE but rather the compiler...

Comment: I am also seeing this compiler error, and as a developer for over 30 years, this is ridiculous. So in 2019 our job as developer is to... not make the compiler work too hard? Compilers have been parsing expressions far, far, far more complex than this for over half a century. This is enforcing coding style via compiler error, which is wrong.

Comment: I'm a seasoned C# and Java developer and am moving into Swift development ... and I just hit this issue.  Seriously?  I'm just using print("my values are " + self.something1 + ", " + ... + ", " + self.something6).  And that's too much for the compiler? I've spat out a list of a 100 variables in c# and the compiler didn't even blink.  This is a joke of a language.

Comment: This is caused by a combinatoric explosion of type-possibilities caused by ExpressibleByXYZLiteral. It's the trade-off: you can write beautiful things like `someDouble / 2` or `let someSet: Set = [1, 2, 3]`, but it increases the burden on the type checker. C# and Java only allow you to use `"abc"` for Strings (and nothing else), and all their Doubles must have a `.` (e.g. you're forced to write `2.0`). I know this problem is annoying, but it's a known trade-off to buy us the ability to have more expressive syntax. See https://www.cocoawithlove.com/blog/2016/07/12/type-checker-issues.html

Answer (score 17):

I have faced similar issue with different scenario

I was trying to create array of string

```
let selectedData = [
        (data?.nose?.stuffyNose) ?? "",
        (data?.nose?.sinusProblems) ?? "",
        (data?.nose?.hayFever) ?? "",
        (data?.nose?.sneezingAttacks) ?? "",
        (data?.nose?.excessiveMucusFormation) ?? ""
]
```

I have already addd Brackets **()**  but still was not working.

---

To fix this I have  added type `[String]`

```
let selectedData:[String] = [
        (data?.nose?.stuffyNose) ?? "",
        (data?.nose?.sinusProblems) ?? "",
        (data?.nose?.hayFever) ?? "",
        (data?.nose?.sneezingAttacks) ?? "",
        (data?.nose?.excessiveMucusFormation) ?? ""
]
```

Hope it is helpful to someone facing same issue

Comment: Why don't you just unwrap `data` and `nose` once, up-front?

Comment: @Alexander this is sample code , there are other entries in array  too ,  For specific requirement I need to pass empty string  in API - May be there are some better ways but this is  code is to show  how compiler stuck

Answer (score 12):

Just try to break up the expression to several simpler subexpression. E.g.:

```
let halfOfViewWidth = cutOutViewWidth.constant / 2
let textWidthAndPadding = options.textWidth + (padding * 2)
let spaceFromRightSide = cutOutViewX.constant + halfOfViewWidth + (textWidthAndPadding / 2)
```

**EDIT**

I noticed that I was able to fix this type of error also by providing explicit type conversions (e.g., instead of relying on the compiler to infer that by multiplying a `CGFloat` with an `Int` it should result in `CGFloat`, I have explicitly converted the `Int` to `CGFloat`). Seems that the problem lies indeed in types and automatic type inference and checking. While breaking up the the complex expression to smaller parts can be very useful to readability, you can solve the problem by being explicit about the types (the error message basically says that the compiler is unable do the type check - thus you can help it by providing explicit types where-ever possible).

Answer (score 6):

I had this error when I accidentally mixed in an optional in an expression. After force unwrapping the error went away.

```
let a : String = "A" 
let b : String = "B" 
let c = letterDictionary["C"]

let imageName : String = a + b + c //error 
let imageName : String = a + b + c! //no error
```

Comment: Thanks. This was indeed masking the underlying error. In my case trying to iterate on a self Protocol.

Answer (score 5):

So I have this kind of expression:

```
return (50 + textHeight) + (dateTextHeight + 16) + (5 + 8) + (16 + 20)
```

I knew I had to breakdown or make this expression shorter to get rid of the error. Like perhaps:

```
return (50 + textHeight) + (dateTextHeight + 16) + 49
```

Although true enough it helped the compiler to do its job, the main cause of the error is the optional Int `textHeight`. I think no matter how long your expression, it should be compile-able.

Answer (score 5):

I see this issue quite regularly when working with SwiftUI, and it's always been the result of a syntax error.  I'm currently using Xcode 11.4.1, and it was true for earlier versions supporting SwiftUI.

For example, I just burned 50 mins with this error because I'd changed the name of a function parameter in another file.  The compiler reported this error in a SwiftUI file that was completely untouched, except it invoked the function without the changed parameter name.  Rather than explicitly pointing out the parameter name mismatch is baulked with this error.

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs when compiler is confused. I ran into it doing a lengthy calculation that mixes various number types

I was able to remedy this by casting various sub-calculations into CGFloat. I did not need to "break up" expressions as suggested by some answers.

- From: (some float expression) * someDouble / someInt
- To: (some float expression) * CGFloat(someDouble / someInt)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem here:

```
@State var sliderpos : CGFloat = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width-32)*(50/100)+(16-20) //causes error
```

But this works :

```
@State var sliderpos : CGFloat = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width-32)*(50/100)-4
```

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me. I was passing two `Float` to a `SwiftUI` struct and subtracting one from the other inside, but by mistake I defined the `Float` inside the as Dates (damn you, copy-paste!).

It was basically this.

```
struct Something: View {
    var minValue: Date
    var maxValue: Date

    var body: some View {
        let valueDifference = maxValue - minValue
    }
}
```

I was calling it like this:

```
let minValue: Float = 0
let maxValue: Float = 1

Something(minValue: minValue, maxValue: maxValue)
```

Note I'm actually passing two `Float`, but the struct is accepting them even though they're defined as `Date`.

As soon as I changed the `Date` types to `Float` the problem was gone.

Answer (score 2):

I had two instances of this so far:

- changed a view that needed a binding as an argument to one using an environmental object but still had a call to MyView($binding) instead of MyView(). In a completely different view, this error appeared. I commented out the most complex code (a switch statement with seven different views) and the compiler found the problem.

– tried something, didn't like it, got into a muddle, caused the error. Discarded all changes rather than trying to unpick the problem; error persisted even though it ran and built ok. Cleaned build folder, error went away.Sent computer to sleep, error came back. Cleaned build folder again, error went away (& project built). Compiler is clearly confused - if this persists, will send project to Apple.
Further observation tells me that it builds and runs fine, the compiler is happy afterwards, thinks about it, and THEN throws the error, which has no effect on the project's ability to run.

I think I got him. I added several more views to the project (for now, without adding them to any view hierarchies, just sitting there quietly), and the error became permanent.
So I looked at the file where the error is marked again, and decided I can do without the group. Since then, I haven't seen the error again.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a memory problem. It happened to me, when I only 350 mb of free memory on my 16GB machine. Using f.e. CleanMyMac -> Free up memory resolved this problem.

Comment: Not a memory problem. The error is reproducible on machines with 24GB of free memory

Comment: Well are you sure that the xCode process can allocate more memory, even if available? There are usually limits on heap and stackssize per process.

Comment: Free up memory worked for me. Free memory was 1.2 of 32 Gb when error come up, after clean 13.29 of 32 Gb build success

Answer (score 1):

By simply doing that :

```
    let array = [Int]()
    let dic   = [Int : Double]()
    
    let tuple = array.map { c -> (a: Int, b: Double) in return (a: c, b: dic[c]!) }.sorted(by: { (first, second) -> Bool in return first.b == second.b ? first.a < second.a : first.b > second.b }).first!
```

Xcode 11.6 takes 10 sec of Cpu with 4 processes running at 100% consuming a lot of  Watts on my MacPro 2019 and i got the error : (The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions)

Even with only a map and a sort combined !

If i split in 2 :

```
let temporaryTupleArrayToAvoidTheCompilerBug = array.map { c -> (a: Int, b: Double) in return (a: c, b: dic[c]!) }

let tuple = temporaryTupleArrayToAvoidTheCompilerBug.sorted(by: { (first, second) -> Bool in return first.b == second.b ? first.a < second.a : first.b > second.b }).first!
```

It works.

The error message is here to hide a bug, the compiler can split the instruction and check the methods syntax separately.

Answer (score 1):

I had an expression with several uses of an optional variable, with fallback values, like this:

```
if ((self.scrollView?.contentSize.width ?? 0.0) > 0.0) && ((self.scrollView?.contentSize.height ?? 0.0) > 0.0) && ((self.scrollView?.frame.size.height ?? 0.0) > 0.0) {
```

The error went away when I made a non-optional copy of the variable:

```
guard let scrollView = self.scrollView else { return }
if (scrollView.contentSize.width > 0.0) && (scrollView.contentSize.height > 0.0) && (scrollView.frame.size.height > 0.0) {
```

Depending on what you want to do when the optional variable is nil, this one-line version could also be useful:

```
if let scrollView = self.scrollView, (scrollView.contentSize.width > 0.0), (scrollView.contentSize.height > 0.0), (scrollView.frame.size.height > 0.0) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue on **Firebase** when updating data for individual keys as per documentation.

```
// Update Cards
        self.database.collection(FirebaseDatabaseKeys.cards).document(docId).setData([
            "id": docId,
            "cardNumber": card.cardNumber ?? "",
            "isFavorite": card.isFavorite,
            "numberOfCards": card.numberOfCards,
            "playerName": card.playerName?.uppercased() ?? "",
            "year": card.year ?? "",
            "sport": card.sport ?? "",
            "brand": card.brand ?? "",
            "set": card.set ?? "",
            "parallel": card.parallel ?? "",
            "serial": card.serial ?? "",
            "owner": uid ?? "",
            CardSide.frontCard.imageKey: "",
            CardSide.backCard.imageKey: ""
        ]) { err in
            if let error = err {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
```

I resolve it creating the dictionary prior to calling `setData`

```
    // Create Data
    let cardData: [String: Any] = [
        "id": docId,
        "cardNumber": card.cardNumber ?? "",
        "isFavorite": card.isFavorite,
        "numberOfCards": card.numberOfCards,
        "playerName": card.playerName?.uppercased() ?? "",
        "year": card.year ?? "",
        "sport": card.sport ?? "",
        "brand": card.brand ?? "",
        "set": card.set ?? "",
        "parallel": card.parallel ?? "",
        "serial": card.serial ?? "",
        "owner": uid ?? "",
        CardSide.frontCard.imageKey: "",
        CardSide.backCard.imageKey: ""
    ]

    // Update Cards
    self.database.collection(FirebaseDatabaseKeys.cards).document(docId).setData(cardData) { err in
        if let error = err {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI, I find this error most often occurs either a) because of a syntax issue, or b) when I'm not properly passing Environment values or Environment Objects down the view chain.

In order to find the issue, I'll usually comment out large sections of code until the Canvas will re-render the preview, then do the same for more specific sections of code. It's tedious and annoying but works.

Answer (score -1):

One **possible** case is that i splice string with enum.

eg:

```
enum Fruit: String {
    case apple
}

let fruit = Fruit.apple
```

then i splice occur the error

```
let url = "/api/" + fruit
```

fruit is a `Enum` field rather than a `String`. I fix with

```
let url = "/api/" + fruit.rawValue
```