# Why does swift give a compiler error after being updated?

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on an e-commerce project and I am now designing a basket page. I have created 4 steppers to determine the quantity of products. I created labels to show the cost of each product and one label for total cost.

```
@IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label3: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label4: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label5: UILabel!

@IBAction func GmS1(_ sender: GMStepper) {
    label1.text = String(sender.value*1.5)
}

@IBAction func GmS2(_ sender: GMStepper) {
    label2.text = String(sender.value*0.89)
}

@IBAction func GmS3(_ sender: GMStepper) {
    label3.text = String(sender.value*26)
}

@IBAction func GmS4(_ sender: GMStepper) {
    label4.text = String(sender.value*4)
}
func calculateSum() {
    label5.text = String([label1, label2, label3, label4].reduce(0,{$0 + (Double($1.text ?? "0") ?? 0)}))
}
```

**calculateSum()** function was solving my problem but after updating swift this code gives the following error:

> "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions."

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Separate, like `let labels: [UILabel] = [label1, label2, label3, label4]; let summed = .reduce(0,{$0 + (Double($1.text ?? "0") ?? 0)}); label5.text = String(summed)`. It's easier to do debug an issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The compiler is unable to type-check this expression swift 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52382645/the-compiler-is-unable-to-type-check-this-expression-swift-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see that error, it usually means that there's a (type) error in that line of code. You need to break up that specific line into several separate statements in order to allow the compiler to reason about it faster. There might not always be an error in your code, but the compiler has a time limit for solving single expressions and if an expression is too complex, it might go over this time limit. You need to break up the expression into separate expressions in this case to allow the compiler to solve each expression separately.

If you move the declaration of the array containing your labels into a separate line, the compiler will be able to solve the expression in a reasonable time.

```
func calculateSum() {
    let labels: [UILabel] = [label1, label2, label3, label4]
    label5.text = String(labels.reduce(0,{$0 + (Double($1.text ?? "0") ?? 0)}))
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what's difference between @Larme comment and your answer?

Comment: @DávidPásztor can you please repost you comment again i want to understand what's the actual difference between comment and your answer.

Comment: @Denis I realized that the issue I was referring to was caused by my code and not the original one, so I deleted my comment and updated my answer. However, as you can see, I actually provide an explanation in my answer rather than just simply giving OP the correctly working code (which is how good answers work on SO). Moreover, as Moritz already stated, a comment is a comment, not an answer. If Larme felt like they wanted to put in more time and provide an answer with an explanation, they could've done so.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation but my concern was to clarify the difference between comment and your answer. Sorry for the down-vote, i correct it.

Comment: For @DávidPásztor's defense, I didn't feel to answer. The issue/answer is quite simple and I just summed it with "Separate". There should have been others questions on SO with the same issue. Sometimes I just comment to pinpoint the solutions (or because I'm not sure of the solution, question being unclear and implicitly asking for details), but let anyone to answer on it with more explanations.